# Is it possible to make a getCommenters() functionality in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

The [DriveApp > File class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) of Google Apps Script has these methods available:

- [`getViewers()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getViewers())
- [`getEditors()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#geteditors)

But **`getCommenters`** method is not available. (This is interesting since `addCommenter`, `addCommenters`, and `removeCommenter` methods are available.)

I'm making a script where I'm changing file and folder permissions based on email addresses in a Spreadsheet. I would like to have a `getCommenters` functionality so I can compare if the commenter emails in the Spreadsheet are already commenters to the file, so there will be no need to again push those emails using `addCommenters`. (Pushing it will generate a new email to the user.) There is no problem in doing this with Viewers and Editors, as the methods are available.

**Question:** Is it possible to create a function that will mimic the supposed functionality of `getCommenters`? Or at least pull an array of email addresses of the commenters?

Answer (score 2):

[`getViewers()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getViewers()) returns viewers and  commentators. You can filter the list using [`getAccess()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getaccessuser):

```
const getCommenters = (file) => 
  file.getViewers().filter(user=>
    file.getAccess(user) == "COMMENT")
```

Comment: Note: The above code will not run on deprecated ES5 engine. To use the code, [upgrade to modern faster V8 engine](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_v8_runtime).

Answer (score -1):

Getting the right nudge from [@TheMaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60398471/2756066), this code worked for what I needed:

```
let file = DriveApp.getFileById('xxxxxxxxxxx-FILE_ID-xxxxxxxxxxx');

let userlist = file.getViewers().filter((user) => file.getAccess(user) == 'COMMENT');

let emaillist = [];

for (var i in userlist) {
  emaillist.push(userlist[i].getEmail());
}
```

Thereafter, `emaillist` becomes an array of email addresses having `COMMENT` permissions.